# Instance method '-UTF8String' not found (return type defaults to 'id')?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I use this method for string encoding.

```
 - (NSString *) URLEncodedString_ch {
   NSMutableString * output = [NSMutableString string];
   const unsigned char * source = (const unsigned char *)[self UTF8String];
  int sourceLen = strlen((const char *)source);
  for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
      const unsigned char thisChar = source[i];
     if (thisChar == ' '){
         [output appendString:@"+"];
      } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' || 
               (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
               (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
               (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
        [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
      } else {
         [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
     }
  }
  return output;
}
```

But I found this error
 "Instance method ' -UTF8String' not found (return type defaults to 'id') ".

I import this like 
"#include Foundation/NSString.h". Because this method is of NSString. But this error is not solved. Please help me.

Comment: Can't you identify which Answer is more useful to you ? You have "Accept-UnAccept" my Answer 3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a NSString category with the following code

in your **NSString+URLEncode.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (URLEncode)

- (NSString *)urlEncode;

@end
```

then in your **NSString+URLEncode.m**

```
#import "NSString+URLEncode.h"

@implementation NSString (URLEncode)

- (NSString *)urlEncode {
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString string];
    const unsigned char *source = (const unsigned char *)[self UTF8String];
    int sourceLen = strlen((const char *)source);
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
        const unsigned char thisChar = source[i];
        if (thisChar == ' '){
            [output appendString:@"+"];
        } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' ||
                   (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
                   (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
                   (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
@end
```

**Usage**

```
#import "NSString+URLEncode.h"

NSString *encodedString = [yourstring urlEncode];
```

Check [Sample Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hefiqu8de39mnwd/NSStringCategorySample.zip)

Comment: Thanks icodebuster. I already used like this but [self UTF8String] method gives error. How to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

`[self UTF8String]` is the problem .This method is supposed to be called on the NSString object

Comment: @AmitGujjar Why are you using this method?Is it an extention class you are using

Comment: I used this method for string encoding like this ..NSString *encodedString = [yourstring urlEncode];

Comment: I got that .If you are not creating an extention class like the one in other answer,self will not be an NSStiring object which causes error.If you are trying to devolop as a method,You will have to give the method with input string and have to apply the inputstring with the UTFString call

Comment: @LithuT.V I agree with you..The above code is for NSString+Category

Answer (score 0):

In case you weren't aware, there's a framework function to do this already -- `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`. You would want to do something like this:

```
NSString* escapedString = [originalString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

No need to reinvent the wheel here.